# Prove $f(z)=-\frac{\log(1-z)}{z}$ is convex in $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

For analytic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ with

> $$f(z)=-\dfrac{\log(1-z)}{z}$$

I want to prove that it's a convex map in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, i.e. that $f$ maps the unit disk conformally onto a convex domain. I know $${\bf Re}\left(1+z\dfrac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right)>0$$
for $z\in\mathbb{D}$, if and only if function be convex in $\mathbb{D}$ [1], but I couldn't use it in my problem. Is the any way to prove that $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{D}$.

Thank.

1. Duren Peter L., Univalent functions (Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 259), Springer-Verlag Berlin and Heidelberg GmbH & Co. K (1983), [p.42](https://books.google.com/books?id=8mVIaZmsy0gC&pg=PA42).

Comment: What is a convex function from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @abx Thanks for your attention. I added the reference!

Comment: I took the freedom and added the definition of convexity from Duren's book into the body of the question.

Comment: I don't know a high level argument, but calculating the image curve of the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ should do the trick…

Comment: Numerical plotting makes it clear that this is true, with the minimum value of $g(z)=\textbf{Re}(1+zf''(z)/f'(z))$ being $g(-1)\approx 0.294$.  Also $f(\mathbb{D})$ fills most of the strip where $x\geq\ln(2)$ and $|y|\leq\pi/2$, but with the left hand end made blunt.  You probably knew that anyway, but you should really include it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalization of f, (f-1)/2 is the image of the fundamental convex function z/(1-z) under the operator H(g) = (2/z)* primitive g.
It is a theorem of Libera (Goodman, Univalent Functions 1983, vol 2, page 156) that while H doesn't preserve the S class (schlicht), it does preserve the classes CV (convex S), ST (starlike S), CC (close to convex S), so the answer to your question follows.
The proof is based on a lemma about p-valent starlike functions (here we need the 2-valent primitive of g, for g in one the S classes above) and a result giving a (necessary) and sufficient condition for a function to belong to P (functions on the unit disk with ReP > 0 and P(0)=1, so it is not obvious

Comment: oops, the normalization is 2*(f-1) as f is 1+z/2+...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof which makes use of Maple, namely, its [DirectSearch](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=101333) package created by Sergey Moiseev. The `GlobalOptima` command finds the global minimum of
$${\Re}\left(1+z\dfrac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right)$$ in the unit disk with the absolute error less than or equal to $10^{-12}$:

```
f := -log(1-z)/z:
A := evalc(Re(eval(1+z*(diff(f, z, z))/(diff(f, z)), z = x+I*y))):
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(A, {x^2+y^2 <= 1}, tolerances = 10^(-12));
```

> [ 0.294349724781047,[x=- 0.999999999999916,y= 0.0000004101682696],498]

```
B := evalc(Re(eval(1+z*(diff(f, z, z))/(diff(f, z)), z = x+I*sqrt(-x^2+1)))):
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(B, {x >= -1, x <= 1}, tolerances = 10^(-12));
```

> [ 0.294349724781044,[x=- 0.999999999999999],126]

These outputs mean that the global minimum equals $0.2943497247810$. I am pretty sure that the results imply the affirmative answer to the question. However, colleagues are welcome to discuss it.

Addition. Just for illustration, here is a plot of A on the unit disk.

```
plot3d(A, y = -sqrt(-x^2+1) .. sqrt(-x^2+1), x = -1 .. 1, axes = frame);
```

[image]

In fact, the function is unbounded from above around $z=1$.

Comment: @MyGlasses: Why do you think so? What place in the above answer is doubtful to you?

Comment: @MyGlasses: Let us consider your function $A(z):=\Re(\dots)$ on $S:=\{z:|z| \le 1 \} \setminus \{z:|z-1| < \frac 1 4 \}$.  The one is harmonic on $S$. Therefore, its minimum is attained on the boundary $\partial S$. Because $A(z)=A(\overline{z})$, the point $z=-1$ is an extremum of $A(z)$ on the boundary $\partial S$. This extremum is the global minimum. The value of $A(-1)$ is calculated numerically. Hope these analytic  arguments would be satisfactory to you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-04/home.html

The original article of Libera<sup>1</sup> is in Proceedings AMS, 16, 1965, p 755-758. freely available at the link above

The proof there is pretty much the one I read in the Goodman book

<sup>1</sup>R. J. Libera. *Some classes of regular univalent functions,*
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 16 (1965), 755-758; [doi: 10.1090/S0002-9939-1965-0178131-2](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1965-0178131-2)